# PCB Design Industry Standard: Hierarchy vs Flat Design

Tags: pcb-design

Is there an industry standard between a flat design vs. hierarchical design? It seems like most people in my group strongly prefer a flat design, but there is one person that is a strong proponent of hierarchical design and one of his big reasons are that "hierarchy is the industry standard." I'm not so sure based on talking to other people I work with, but this is my first job out of college so I'm really not sure.

Comment: Good luck with flat design of something sufficiently complex like even simplest CPU (well, it's not PCB, but you get the idea).

Comment: Depends a lot on the complexity of the design. If there are 10 parts it would be a bit silly to force it into a hiearchical mold. If there are multiple BGAs with scores or hundreds of pins  then you need some way to manage the complexity.

Comment: A hierarchical design is NOT the industry standard. You choose the option that suits the design and, in most cases I've come across, the designs are usually flat. I've never actually made a hierarchical design in all my years and sometimes the schematics are quite big and, I'm sure some folk would say too cumbersome. However, personally, I have no problem reading a big single sheet drawing. On the other hand I've come across engineers who have pointlessly used hierarchical designs and just added a pointless complexity level to being able to read it.

Comment: @Andyaka I think having one single big sheet helps a lot.

Answer (score 6):

> "most people in my group"

I'm guessing they don't re-use designs and/or are the only person working on the schematic? It certainly is easier to hit the ground running with flat. But it gets old when you hit the ground running only to repeat the same thing you did before.

I work alone and started doing things hierarchically because:

- I was sick of needing to make 10 identical changes to 10 identical schematic blocks whenever I wanted to change one
  thing.
- I wanted to make a readable schematic
- I wanted to be able to re-use schematic blocks.

I was led to the existence of hierarchical design after I realized buses and netgroups existed and begain looking into them to make more readable, re-usable schematics. It's kind of like writing your own code library. Takes planning.

Comment: 100% I am a fan of hierarchical for navigation and re-use. Unfortunately there are too many people who "don't understand" and are in position of influence and force designs to be flat and all it does is causes ERRORS, especially when repeated blocks exist and one is missed..

Comment: I agree with most, but having done both big hierarchical designs and big flat designs, I will tell you that making a big flat design takes *more* planning than hierarchical. It all comes back down to your first bullet. Its rather easy to push changes into a hierarchical design, maybe add/delete/rename a few busses. With a flat design that is all pure horror. Needless to say, I made a big flat design only once lol

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen a hierarchical PCB design done in our division.  And believe me, after 53 years in the industry, I've seen quite a few of them!

All of our designs are flat, sometimes running 30, 40, or more pages.  Just came across one that 90 sheets!

Most of our designs have very little reuse to them from job to job, so there's not a lot to be gained by trying to force a hierarchical structure on them.  And even within a given board, there is usually very little of the circuitry that is repeated that would make it worthwhile to develop a sub-block of a particular function.  Something like a simple diff-amp may fall in that category, but what's to be saved by replacing an op amp and 4 resistors with a square block with 2 inputs and 1 output, plus 2 more if you want to include power.

Now if you're talking about an FPGA design using graphical tools, then that would be a different story.

Comment: How do you make those schematics readable?

Comment: Breaking a schematic into pages in a way that makes sense is kind of hierarchical breakdown too.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I find readability ends when you can't immediately tell where connections on a page are going if it's going to more than one place. Which gets pretty easy when you have one IC going to two places or two ICs each going to different places,

Comment: All of these issues can be addressed by having drafting standards (yeah, I know engineers don't to follow processes).  For example, one requires that all IO of the PCB be on the first n pages of the schematic.  Another requires that page bubbles be used (the schematic captures may enforce these automatically) that shows to what other pages of the schematic a signal goes to.

Comment: And in so far as showing connectivity on page, that's more of a judgement call between connecting devices together by using a common signal name and actually drawing the connection from device 1 to device 2 to device 3, ...

Comment: I don't consider 30, 40 pages a flat design. You've just been doing ad-hoc hierarchical design. A 10 meter by 8 meter single page design is flat.

Comment: I disagree.  Whether it fits on one page or many does not determine whether it's a flat or hierarchical design.  A D-size sheet is the standard for our drawings.  This allows a single page to viewed comfortable on computer monitor.  And we use as many D-size sheets as needed.

Comment: But what are the *benefits* of flat design for such big designs, though? Apart from "works well enough".

Comment: Most of our designs & associated schematics do not lend them themselves to a step-and-repeat topology.  There is very little in a typical design that is duplicated, or repeated multiple times.  Heck, in the 90 sheet design I referenced in my answer, it takes 10 sheets just to show the KU060 FPGA part of the design.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with whatever makes sense for the design, products, and/or workplace culture. I primarily like to make the schematic readable for me and others which will push me towards using hierarchical or flat. If you reuse circuitry between different projects, hierarchical designs are great. For small to medium projects, hierarchical designs seem overkill, plus, there is a tendency these days to split the schematic in to lots of pages when one or two pages would do.

Personally, I'm a fan of one page designs (E-size is fine by me) but will normally do a flat design and have logical divisions between pages (core logic, power supplies, power connections on FPGAs, I/O, ...). What I don't like, and see quite often, are 30 page schematics (flat and hierarchical) that could have been easily drawn on significantly less pages, especially analog designs.

For multichannel designs, hierarchical schematics work very well compared to flat designs. Plus, some layout software (Altium, in my case) allows you to duplicate the channel layout with ease.

There is a case for hierarchical designs due to software issues. In Altium, once you have 100+ nets+components on a page, the program becomes very sluggish, like taking 6 seconds for each step on larger schematics. To overcome this, I will work on a smaller section of interest on a separate page, then copy it to the master page. Of course, I could have used a hierarchical design that would keep things snappy, but, possibly less readable.

Comment: Yeah multi-channel was what made me start looking for other options because I couldn't fit all the input conditioning to the one ADC without splitting the channels up to different pages which means splitting up the ADC to different pages.

Comment: And we do things like that -splitting a component across multiple pages - as a matter of course.

Comment: @SteveSh When I say splitting channels to different pages, I mean don't mean just splitting up a component between boards which is normal. For example, putting all the inputs into one component block and putting the output to another. I mean needing to split it up to the extent where you have a component blocks that only have a single pin each on their own page.